# Returning value from loop inside filter without auxiliar variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have this block of code, but, for this to work I needed to create a auxiliar variable to store the value. Is possible to do it without that variable? Maybe a more functional approach?

```
    const filterSo = response => {
    return response.filter((item) => {
        let shoudlReturn = false;
        for (let key in item) {
            if (filters[lowerFirst(key)]) {
                shoudlReturn = filters[lowerFirst(key)] === item[key];
            }
        }
        return shoudlReturn;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer is boolean, you can return as soon as you know that the answer is `true`. Change the condition to use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to check both cases, and if both are `true` to return immediately.

```
const filterSo = response => response.filter((item) => {
  for (let key in item) {
    if (filters[lowerFirst(key)] && filters[lowerFirst(key)] === item[key]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Just a small note: Technically this is not the same as the OP's code, but is most likely what he's after.

Comment: My thought exactly :)

Comment: Worked, thank you! And thanks for the link as well, will be really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could simplify your code as follows!

```
const filterSo = response => 
   response.filter (item => 
      Object.keys (item)
            .map (lowerFirst)
            .some (key => filters[key] && filters[key] === item[key])
    )
```